# Generating markup for different object types in a spring MVC application

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jstl

In the current project I'm working on, we have multiple object types that require a different presentation.

To give you an example, say we have a BankApplication superclass and two subclasses called AccountApplication and LoanApplication that inherit from the superclass. Each of them would be presented differently on the view.

When we get to the JSP we have a list of applications of any of the mentioned subtypes. I've seen a lot of code like:

```
<c:set value="${application.class.name}" var="applicationType" />
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${applicationType == 'LoanApplication'}">
        <ourLib:displayLoanApplication application="${application}"/>
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="${applicationType == 'AccountApplication'}">
        <ourLib:displayAccountApplication application="${application}"/>
    </c:when>
    ...
</c:choose>
```

I'm wondering if there is a better way to handle this. I've thought about having each class implement their own view, but that sounds about as ugly as the current approach. Generating html inside the class is not only ugly, but I also have to deal with string concatenations and other stuff that I'd rather avoid.

Another alternative I considered is loading up a jsp/freemarker/velocity template and spitting out the html from the classes. This would allow me to edit the templates separately from the code (good thing). But I haven't seen any documentation on this, and I'm not even sure it's a good approach. Also, would I really want to have jsp/freemarker/velocity dependencies inside a simple POJO? That sounds like overkill.

What alternatives/patterns would you suggest for presenting different markup depending on the kind of object? Maybe our current approach is not as bad as I perceive it.

Comment: Tiles can be a good fit for this; where some viewnames have similar structures but you swap out inner parts of the template in different views http://tiles.apache.org/ this way you could have two completely different viewnames for LoadApplication and AccountApplication, and simply solve the problem by having different JSP templates for the different objects.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is to include a template depending on the simple class name. Like this you can easily avoid having these choose blocks all over the place.

I'm currently using Thymeleaf but i'm certain that "any" template engine provides a similar include functionality.

Here's one example in Thymeleaf

```
<div th:include"entity/__${currentClass.simpleName}__ :: editor">this will be replaced by a template like 'entity/Task' with the fragment 'editor'</div>
```

You can also just use any available variable in the view model to do this instead of a class name.